# Color difference between an android device to a computer screen

Tags: java, android, colors, color-management

Lately I was developing to android. While I was running my application I encountered a major color difference between the colors in design mode to the actual appearance of the colors in my phone's screen.

I am using HTC one M7.

The phenomenon was something like this:

The desired color #FFFDE64B:

[image]

The way it actually appears is something like this #FFEFFF02:

[image]

A solution which achieved the desired color was to choose a warmer color #FFFFC44E:

[image]

But its not the ideal solution because for me to be able to design better I need a design mode which uses the original colors.

Is this a common phenomenon? If does, how do I get a consistence between the appearance in design mode to runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a common phenomenon, but not only in this scenario.

Every display has it's own [color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_space). This means the color you see in your computer has certain coordinates referred to an origin, but its not the same origin in every color space or device.

If you want to achieve perfection you have to calibrate your monitor, [check this example](http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/monitor-calibration.htm).

Comment: By deciding that my HTC one screen is more calibrated I was able to determine what is the final appearance of my colors. The calibration of my Samsung monitor was done by enabling an option which called "magicColor".

Answer (score 0):

ya.. this is a common phenomenon. It would be better to use a real device for design, development and testing purposes.

For details, check this

http://www.guru99.com/real-device-vs-emulator-testing-ultimate-showdown.html

Also, you can try calibrating your monitor. For refs, check this

http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/monitor-calibration.htm